# Material UI - why InputBase ref is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI Select component, with Material-UI InputBase to show the values.

I need access for the ref of the ROOT of the Input component, but it's not working and the current of the ref is undefined.

I tried using the prop way: `ref={inputRef}`

I also tried the callback ref: `ref={(ref) => inputRef.current = ref}`

nothing works.

to make it clear i need the ref of the root element, not the inner inputRef.

**Select component**

```
import Input from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';    

const MySelect = (props) => {
   const inputRef = useRef<any>();

   return (<Select
      input={
        <Input
          ref={inputRef}
          onClick={() => console.log(inputRef.current)} // output: undefined
        />
      }
    >
      {props.menuItems}
    </Select>}
```

}

**EDIT 1 - FROM THE DOCS**

Again, i need the ROOT element ref. NOT the inputRef. i need
the div wrapping the native input element.

https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/

[image]

**EDIT 2 - code sandbox**

here is a sandbox link to view the issue live: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-olbo2?file=/demo.tsx

**Edit 3**

it is confirmed by MUI that it is a bug -
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27792

Answer (score 3):

### **ref is only available on native HTML element**

For `InputBase` you will need to access native input ref via `inputRef` instead of `ref`.

Reference: [here](https://material-ui.com/api/input-base/)

Comment: from the docs: "The ref is forwarded to the root element."

Comment: Hey, I can't get your idea. It references the input native element. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: i need the root element. the container of the native input.  check the edit of this post.

Answer (score 0):

for me it worked by not calling the ref prop "ref" but something like refObj and doing this:

```
ref={(element) => {
        if (refObj) {
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
           refObj.current = element;
        }
     }}
```